# Why do Python generator functions not have a syntactically different notation from 'regular' functions?

Tags: python, syntax, generator, pep

I am wondering, after reading about generators in [Improve Your Python: 'yield' and Generators Explained](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/), but not having experimented with them yet, why the syntactic notation for a generator function is not different from that of a regular function. The most obvious choice, in my thought experiment, would be:

```
generator generator_name(param):
    # ...
    yield some_other_value
```

Instead of:

```
def generator_name(param):
    # ...
    yield some_value
```

Now, when one is reading Python code, it seems that one needs to search for the word 'yield' first before understanding that some function is a generator function. Or, is there a Python convention that demands generator functions have a indicative name? like `generate_some_value_from_y`?

Comment: Because functions that can be treated as generator functions aren't fundamentally different from normal functions. You can use them in all the places that you can use non-generator functions.

Comment: Because a generator function is not itself a generator, it *produces* a generator.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes, entirely clear, can you Answer this? than i can mark it resolved. Also i just found out about that when reading this S.O. post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/231855#231855

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from [PEP 255](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/), the proposal that introduced generators to Python, where Guido van Rossum (the Benevolent Dictator for Life, BDFL) explains why there is no separate keyword:

> *Issue*:  Introduce another new keyword (say, `gen` or `generator`) in place of `def`, or otherwise alter the syntax, to distinguish generator-functions from non-generator functions.
>
> *Con*:  In practice (how you think about them), generators *are* functions, but with the twist that they're resumable.  The mechanics of how they're set up is a comparatively minor technical issue, and introducing a new keyword would unhelpfully overemphasize the mechanics of how generators get started (a vital but tiny part of a generator's life).
>
> *Pro*:  In reality (how you think about them), generator-functions are actually factory functions that produce generator-iterators as if by magic.  In this respect they're radically different from non-generator functions, acting more like a constructor than a function, so reusing `def` is at best confusing.  A `yield` statement buried in the body is not enough warning that the semantics are so different.
>
> *BDFL*:  `def` it stays.  No argument on either side is totally convincing, so I have consulted my language designer's intuition.  It tells me that the syntax proposed in the PEP is exactly right - not too hot, not too cold.  But, like the Oracle at Delphi in Greek mythology, it doesn't tell me why, so I don't have a rebuttal for the arguments against the PEP syntax.  The best I can come up with (apart from agreeing with the rebuttals ... already made) is "FUD".  If this had been part of the language from day one, I very much doubt it would have made Andrew Kuchling's "Python Warts" page.

In essence, a generator function *produces* a generator, it is not a generator itself.